# Export DataGridView Data with Images into Excel, HTML, or Word with Proper Table Formatting

Tags: c#, image, excel, datagrid, export

I have a data grid view with images loaded into it.  The table which is the source for this data grid has path for images and I load images using that path.  I have tried to export data to Excel and was successful, but it seems to show some problems with images.  Please any help?  Any help instead of Excel, HTML, or Word or anything would do, but please provide detailed help or it causes a lot of problems.

Here is the code I used to export to Excel:

```
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (!saveFileDialog1.FileName.Equals(String.Empty))
                {
                    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                    if (f.Extension.Equals(".xls"))
                    {
                        Excel.Application xlApp;
                        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
                        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                        int i = 0;
                        int j = 0;

                        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                        {
                            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                            {

                                DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                                xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                                if (cell.Value.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))
                                {
                                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = ReadFile((Bitmap)cell.Value);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                        xlApp.Quit();

                        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                        releaseObject(xlApp);

                        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file " + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid file type");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You did pick a location " +
                                    "to save file to");
                }
            }
```

Table format is:

ax_no
rm_no
fullName
Types
photograph // path of file.
Fingerprint // path of file.

All are strings.  I have also tried using Spire.dataExport and iTextSharp but it doesn't work.

Comment: You say you experienced some problems with images.  What were those problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to place image into cell try this code:

```csh
if (cell.Value.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))
{
    // You have to get original bitmap path here
    string imagString = "bitmap1.bmp";
    Excel.Range oRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1]; 
    float Left =(float) ((double)oRange.Left);
    float Top =(float) ((double)oRange.Top);
    const float ImageSize=32;
    xlWorkSheet1.Shapes.AddPicture(imagString, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, ImageSize, ImageSize);
    oRange.RowHeight = ImageSize + 2;
}
else
{
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this was the correct answer . now i am able to do it. was looking for this solution..
Thanks @Dos095-russ Perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article [Exporting a DataGridView to an Excel/PDF/image file by using Reporting Services report generation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/ReportExporters_WinForms.aspx).

Also check out [Infragistics Winforms Controls Bundle](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms.aspx#Overview). It has very customizable UltraWinGrid to visualize your table data and powerful Excel libraries that does not require Excell installed to use.

And finally take a look at Stimulsoft Reports: it has a lot export formats and does not require Excel application too.

Comment: My problem is not about exporting to excel
Its about inserting an image into an excel cell using C# or vb.net
or maybe in any format but need that image in the datagrid to be place in the same row and column into the exported file(excel/word/html) but not access not database.